# setListAdapter not displaying contents

Tags: android

I was trying to implement a custom adapter by parsing `JSON` using `setListAdapter`. Everything looks fine but nothing displays on the phone screen.
Except lines. Please help me with this. The `JSON` is parsing succeesully and getting stored in `ArrayList` `jsonlist`.

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    final String TAG = "MAINActivity.java";
    ListView listView;
    private static final String STATION = "stationName";
    private static final String DOCKS = "availableDocks";

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> jsonlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    private Context context;
    ListView lv ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new AsynctaskParseJson(MainActivity.this).execute();
    //  listView=(ListView)findViewById();
    }

    public class AsynctaskParseJson extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        private ListActivity activity;
        private ProgressDialog dialog;
        public AsynctaskParseJson(ListActivity mainActivity) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

            this.activity = mainActivity;
            context = activity;
            dialog=new ProgressDialog(context);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            this.dialog.setMessage("Progress start");
            this.dialog.show();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
        private Context context;
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
            /*ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>>(
                    context, R.layout.list_item, jsonlist);*/
            Log.d("JSON LIST", "Headline: " + jsonlist.toString());
            Log.d("Elements", "Headline: " + context.toString());
            Log.d("Elements", "Station: " + STATION);

            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, jsonlist, R.layout.list_item, new String[] { STATION, DOCKS}, new int[] { R.id.editText1, R.id.editText2 });

            setListAdapter(adapter);
            lv = getListView();
            getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        }

        String strURL = "http://www.citibikenyc.com/stations/json";
        JSONArray jArray = null;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject jObject = jParser.getJSONFromURL(strURL);
            //Log.e("NITIN", "Headline: " + jObject);
            try {
                jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("stationBeanList");
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String headLine = c.getString(STATION);
                    String agency = c.getString(DOCKS);
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put(headLine, STATION);
                    map.put(agency, DOCKS);
                    jsonlist.add(map);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

JSON parser class:

```
public class JSONParser {
    final String TAG = "JsonParser.java";
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String jSon = "";

    public JSONObject getJSONFromURL(String strURL) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(strURL);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line + "\n");
            }
            //Log.e("Nitin", "Builder: " + builder.toString());
            is.close();
            jSon = builder.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(jSon);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
        return jObj;
    }

}
```

Comment: post the code for your adapter

Comment: Try to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter.